# How to change 'out of stock' to 'Sorry sold out'

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento (v1.9.3.1) I want to replace 'Out of Stock' to 'Sorry sold out'
Which file I need to edit please? I want a solution that is not lost after migration.

Comment: change in `Mage_Catalog.csv` file of your store language  folder in locale folder

Comment: Sorry this didn't work /app/locale/en_US. Line 468 / 469 changed to 'Sold Out'. Flush Magento Cache. Logged out & login.

Comment: SOLVED: I updated these files /app/design/frontend/mytheme/mychildtheme/template/catalog/product
Files: list.phtml & view.phtml

Answer (score 1):

If you did not change template setting, you should look for it in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template` folder. There are some places that you need to change:

1. Product view: in `catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml`
2. Product list: `catalog/product/list.phtml` 
   You should also find different places for different types of products as well.

Or I think you can change by editing CSV translation file (`app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv`).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution which makes it possible to do things well and allowing to not modify the phtml file is to change the translation file `app/locale/language_ISO/Mage_Catalog.csv`In the line about 465 `"Out of Stock","Sorry sold out"`

**EDIT:**
If you haven't modified the phtml, check please if you have this piece of code:

`<?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?>`

Comment: Sorry what is the advantage of this over solution below? I don't want it to be overwritten after an upgrade.

Comment: Excuse me but I have given you the best way to do it, there is no other way I think, as for your changes you have to save the file that you modified then you make a merge. If you plan to modify the phtml it will be even worse and I advise against it. The translation functions are made for this.

Comment: Thanks but I have this directory app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv + it doesn't work. I have cleared cache as well.

Comment: Where you want to display this "Sorry sold out" in `catalog/product/view/view.phtml` right ? it should work and you should have `<?php echo $this->helper('catalog')->__('Out of stock') ?>` in the phtml If you have not modified it

Answer (score 1):

app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml

```
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Places Available') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('All Booked - Please Contact Us') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying you want to migrate then you can use **database(inline) translation** because database translation will migrate to migento2

so here is the example how you can translate the word in.

http://inchoo.net/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/

please check above tutorial will teach you how to use database(inline) translation.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for pointing me in right direction. After some trial I solved it by updating below files.

```
/app/design/frontend/mytheme/mychildtheme/template/catalog/product
Files: list.phtml & view.phtml
```